# Bindable LINQ libraries or "why Obtics is not actively maintained anymore"

Tags: c#, .net, linq, binding

The ultimate task is: bind some WPF controls to LINQ queries.

Having searched for "Bindable LINQ" I've found multiple references to [Obtics](http://obtics.codeplex.com/), [Bindable Linq](http://www.codeplex.com/bindablelinq) and [Continuous LINQ](http://clinq.codeplex.com/). They do what I want to, but one thing confuses me: their age. Seems like their development stopped at nearly the same time somewhere in 2009-2010, which is suspicious.

Is it still reasonable to use them? Haven't they eventually been superseded by some standard library means?

Comment: Why you need any library for this? Are you working on some Framework?

Comment: @sll I want to make a view model, which aggregates data from two observable collections, i.e. something like `from a in A join b in B on a.id equals b.id select new VM(a, b)`

Comment: Are objects in both collections of the same type?

Comment: @sll unfortunately, different - that's the reason for having a VM at all...

Comment: Use [LINQ Zip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) method to aggregate two collections. I'm still not sure what is your question

Comment: @sll zip() operates sequentially pairwise, that's not what I need (a join). And it doesn't return an `IObservableCollection` to bind UI to.

Comment: Hi Vines, did you come to any conclusions about these libs?

Comment: @mcintyre321 I've found OLinq, and I know that you already did! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research:

1. I've found [OLinq](https://github.com/wasabii/OLinq). It is maintained and quite functional. Some Linq operations are missing, but it's fairly expandable by design.
2. I haven't seen any mentions of how good or bad such a solution is. Looks like it's simply uncommon.

Comment: I still use Obtics even on a production... can you believe this? I really love IValueProvider and ExpressionObserver... can OLinq observe an arbitary expression like Obtics do?

Comment: @DmitryGusarov You could share your knowledge as a full-fledged answer =) I don't know much about Obtics, so I'm not sure how to answer your question. FWIW, OLinq is basically a reimplementation of Linq, and some of operations are still missing (I personally lack `join`s).

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce my library [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations). It is production ready library sutable for bind WPF controls to LINQ like queries.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are [Reactive Extensions](http://reactivex.io/) ([Rx.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive)).
For working with WPF MVVM there´s a library called [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/).

Then you can use [ReactiveList](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/obsolete/collections/reactive-list) instead of `ObservableCollection` and just define your linq querys on that list.

code form their documentation:

```cs
DocumentList = new ReactiveList<Document>() {
    ChangeTrackingEnabled = true,
};

DocumentList.ItemChanged
    .Where(x => x.PropertyName == "IsDirty" && x.Sender.IsDirty)
    .Select(x => x.Sender)
    .Subscribe(x => {
        Console.WriteLine("Make sure to save {0}!", x.DocumentName);
    });
```